# set the default selected item as the same for a value get from DB in Django

Tags: html, django

I have a web app using Django as the backend.
In the frontend, there's a selection box.

The default selection should be the same as a value get from DB.

```
  {% with query_results_book_discard_reason=query_results_book_discard_reason|index:forloop.parentloop.counter0 %}
            <select style="display: none" name="discard_reason" class="MySelect">
                            <option value="">--Select--</option>
                            <option value="Change edition">Change edition</option>
                            <option value="Change to eTextbook">Change to eTextbook</option>
                            <option value="Change title">Change title</option>
                            <option value="No material required">No material required</option>
                        </select>
{% endwith %}
```

{{ query_results_book_discard_reason.discard_reason }} is the value from DB that would match the selection box.

If {{ query_results_book_discard_reason.discard_reason }} is equal to "Change edition", the default selected item should be "Change edition" in the selection box.

If {{ query_results_book_discard_reason.discard_reason }} is equal to "Change to eTextbook", the default selected item should be "Change to eTextbook" in the selection box.
...

If {{ query_results_book_discard_reason.discard_reason }} is equal to None, the selection box should be original.

How could managed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Selected option has attribute 'selected' as in:

```
<option value="Change edition" selected>Change edition</option>
```

Thus, the most straightforward solution would be to add to every option:

```
    <option value="Change edition"
     {% if query_results_book_discard_reason.discard_reason == "Change edition"  %}
     selected 
     {% endif %} >
    Change edition
    </option>
```

A better solution would be to run a short JS script on load that would add selected attribute to the right option